# Is there a measure to find the distance between different sized, unsorted arrays of numbers?

Tags: arrays, distance, similarity

Say I have a arrays of numbers, such as [2,6,3,4]. I would like a way to quantify the distance between this array and other arrays. Some sort of similarity measure that behaves according to the following rules:

1. The order of the elements in the array shouldn't matter. So the distance between [2,6,3,4] and [2,3,4,6] should be ideally zero.
2. The array can be of different sizes. So I'd like a similarity measure between array such as [2,6,3,4] and [2,6,3,4,6], or [2,6,3,4] and [2,4].
3. It should have some resistance to outliers. For example, [1,2,3] should be similar to [1,2,3,100]

Is there any method that does something similar to this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: *It should have some resistance to outliers. For example, `[1,2,3]` should be similar to `[1,2,3,100]`.* This is quite vague. You should give more examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok this can be a solution:

1) Since you said `The order of the elements in the array shouldn't matter`, so that gives me some freeness to sort. So all the arrays you have first have to be sorted specifically ascending.

2)After individual sorting of each array, the collection of arrays have to be **[lexicographically sorted](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order)**. You might have to convert your arrays to `String variables`. You can use `Comparable` or `Comparator` for implementing the lexicographical sort.

3) After lexicographical sort... similar arrays will be close enough to each other. If consecutive arrays have same length then calculate **Euclidean distance** for more measure.
 So there it is.. all arrays sorted and similar arrays are close by :)

**NOTE:**
Lexicographical Sort gives you the advantage of not calculating the distance between different sized arrays and yet have order between them :)

Answer (score 0):

You can sort then take the [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance).